# how to set li class to active on "next" button click and on nav-item click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already have JS that will change the navbar li class to active on navbar click as shown below, that works fine. But I also have a "next" button that should also do the same thing on click, change the li class of the nav bar to active. The button is set to hide the current tab, and show the next tab so the users wont have to keep scrolling up to click the next tab. No matter what i've done i cant get this to work.

this is the working JS that changes the li class to active on nav-item click. But i cant get it to work with the the next button for some reason.

```js
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("navsub");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}

function showStuff(element)  {
        var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
        for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 
            tabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        
        var tabContentIdToShow = element.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-$1');
        document.getElementById(tabContentIdToShow).style.display = 'block';
    }
function nxtbtn() {
  var header = document.getElementById("navsub");
  var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("button1");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    element[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="navsub" class="navsub">


  <li class="nav-item active"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs1">Contact Info</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs2">Case</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs3">Processor</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs4">Cooling</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs5">RAM</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs6">Storage</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs7">Power Supply</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs8">Fans, Lighting & Sleeving</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs9">Accessories</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showStuff(this)" id="tabs10">Graphics Card</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="buttonl"><a  onclick="showStuff(this);" id="tabs2" class="button1 medium blue2">Continue</a></div>
```

I have made a js function `function nxtbtn()` so that i run the function when the next button is clicked but it doesnt actually do anything :/ The one i cant get to work is this one

I'm at a loss as to what to do. I feel as if its something super simple im just overlooking

here is the showStuff js too for whatever reason.

```
function showStuff(element)  {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 
        tabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    var tabContentIdToShow = element.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-$1');
    document.getElementById(tabContentIdToShow).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: why are you using HTML `<a>` tags if you don't need to link it makes your code inconsistent

Comment: What JS `showStuff(this)` is supposed to be ?

Comment: it would still be wiser to use this css code `#navsub > li > a  { cursor: pointer; }` rather than adding to each line `style="cursor:pointer;"`

Comment: there cannot be 2 elements with the same ID, your HTML is not valid

Comment: using a click event on an input `type=text` is suspect.

Comment: The a tags are there because some of them will be linked. they just aren't yet. the showStuff(this) is to show and hide the various tabs that part isnt even relevant but here it is

function showStuff(element)  {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 
        tabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    var tabContentIdToShow = element.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-$1');
    document.getElementById(tabContentIdToShow).style.display = 'block';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do that this way...

```js
const
  navSub_LI  = document.querySelectorAll('#navsub > li')
, contents   = document.querySelectorAll('#Contents > p')
, btNext     = document.querySelector('#bt-next')
, setContent = ref => contents.forEach((p,i) => p.classList.toggle('noDisplay',  p.dataset.ref !== ref ))
  ;
navSub_LI.refIndex = [...navSub_LI].findIndex(li=>li.classList.contains('active'))
setContent( navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref )

navSub_LI.forEach((li,indx,arr) => 
  {
  li.onclick = () =>
    {
    navSub_LI.refIndex = indx
    setContent( navSub_LI[indx].dataset.ref )
    arr.forEach(z=>z.classList.toggle('active',z===li))
    }
  })
btNext.onclick = () =>
  {
  navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex++].classList.remove('active')
  if (navSub_LI.refIndex >= navSub_LI.length) navSub_LI.refIndex--
  navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].classList.add('active')
  setContent( navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].dataset.ref )
  }
```

```css
#navsub > li { cursor: pointer; }
#navsub > li.active { text-decoration:underline red; }
.noDisplay { display : none; }
```

```html
<ul id="navsub">
  <li class="active" data-ref="info" > Contact Info              </li>
  <li                data-ref="case" > Case                      </li>
  <li                data-ref="proc" > Processor                 </li>
  <li                data-ref="cool" > Cooling                   </li>               
  <li                data-ref="ram_" > RAM                       </li>
  <li                data-ref="stor" > Storage                   </li>
  <li                data-ref="powr" > Power Supply              </li>
  <li                data-ref="FL&S" > Fans, Lighting & Sleeving </li>
  <li                data-ref="acc_" > Accessories               </li>
  <li                data-ref="gpca" > Graphics Card             </li>
</ul>

<button id="bt-next">Next</button> 
  
<div id="Contents">
  <p data-ref="info" > content Contact Info              </p>
  <p data-ref="case" > content Case                      </p>
  <p data-ref="proc" > content Processor                 </p>
  <p data-ref="cool" > content Cooling                   </p>
  <p data-ref="ram_" > content RAM                       </p>
  <p data-ref="stor" > content Storage                   </p>
  <p data-ref="powr" > Pcontent Power Supply             </p>
  <p data-ref="FL&S" > content Fans, Lighting & Sleeving </p>
  <p data-ref="acc_" > content Accessories               </p>
  <p data-ref="gpca" > content Graphics Card             </p>
</div>
```

## the same with `<div>` elements for contents, and Next / Prev buttons

```js
const
  navSub_LI  = document.querySelectorAll('#navsub > li')
, contents   = document.querySelectorAll('#Contents > div')
, btNext     = document.querySelector('#bt-next')
, btPrev     = document.querySelector('#bt-prev')
  ;
navSub_LI.refIndex = [...navSub_LI]
  .findIndex(li => li.classList.contains('active'))

navPrevNext()

navSub_LI.forEach((li, indx, arr) => 
  {
  li.onclick = () => 
    {
    navSub_LI.refIndex = indx
    arr.forEach(z => z.classList.toggle('active', z === li))
    navPrevNext()
    }
  })
  
btNext.onclick = () => navPrevNext( +1 )
btPrev.onclick = () => navPrevNext( -1 )

function navPrevNext( moving = 0)
  {
  let newPosition = navSub_LI.refIndex + moving
  
  if ( moving !== 0 )
    {
    navSub_LI[navSub_LI.refIndex].classList.remove('active')
    navSub_LI[newPosition].classList.add('active')
    navSub_LI.refIndex = newPosition
    }

  btNext.disabled = (newPosition === (navSub_LI.length -1))
  btPrev.disabled = (newPosition === 0 ) 
 
  // setContent ...
  let ref = navSub_LI[newPosition].dataset.ref
 
  contents.forEach( div => 
    div.classList.toggle('noDisplay', div.dataset.ref !== ref)
    )  
  }
```

```css
#navsub > li { cursor: pointer; }
#navsub > li.active { text-decoration:underline red; }
.noDisplay { display : none; }
```

```html
<ul id="navsub">
  <li class="active" data-ref="info" > Contact Info              </li>
  <li                data-ref="case" > Case                      </li>
  <li                data-ref="proc" > Processor                 </li>
  <li                data-ref="cool" > Cooling                   </li>               
  <li                data-ref="ram_" > RAM                       </li>
  <li                data-ref="stor" > Storage                   </li>
  <li                data-ref="powr" > Power Supply              </li>
  <li                data-ref="FL&S" > Fans, Lighting & Sleeving </li>
  <li                data-ref="acc_" > Accessories               </li>
  <li                data-ref="gpca" > Graphics Card             </li>
</ul>

<button id="bt-prev">Prev</button> 
<button id="bt-next">Next</button> 

<div id="Contents">
  <div data-ref="info"> content Contact Info              </div>
  <div data-ref="case"> content Case                      </div>
  <div data-ref="proc"> content Processor                 </div>
  <div data-ref="cool"> content Cooling                   </div>
  <div data-ref="ram_"> content RAM                       </div>
  <div data-ref="stor"> content Storage                   </div>
  <div data-ref="powr"> Pcontent Power Supply             </div>
  <div data-ref="FL&S"> content Fans, Lighting & Sleeving </div>
  <div data-ref="acc_"> content Accessories               </div>
  <div data-ref="gpca"> content Graphics Card             </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works flawlessly but i cant get it to work alongside everything else. my ShowStuff script uses an a id  called tabs# to show different tab pages. the below example shows the tab on click based on but it doesnt set the current tab page li to active. this is because its relying on ids i think?  example
.
 <div id="bt-next"><a id="tabs3" onclick="showStuff(this);" class="button1 medium blue2">Next</a></div>
    <div id="bt-prev"><a  id="tabs2" class="button1 medium orange2">Back</a></div>

Comment: @KenDeadmausMitchell changed my code with the use of [dataset attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: I haven't ever messed with datasets, this is fantastic! I'm doing some more reading on QuerySelector, and datasets to use it more often. You're the bees knees!

Comment: I edited it so that it will look for div tags, instead of p so that it is able to take pasted in html. Exactly what I needed, and a thousand times easier! How does one +rep on here? lol

Comment: @KenDeadmausMitchell Beginners aside, I don't believe there's a single coder on earth who can accept a change in their programming style. avoid doing this in the future.